# PWA - iOS change Status Bar color

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to change the color of the Status Bar in a Progressive Web App on iOS 11.3 Beta 6? Tried to change the HEX Code of `background_color` and `theme_color` in the `manifest.json` file but I couldn't achieve any changes.

[image: Status Bar]

Answer (score 7):

Well you could use the

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

To make the status bar transparent (not invisible) and use a div behind the status bar of whatever color that you like. [Framework 7](https://framework7.io/docs/statusbar.html) does this by allowing you to change the color of

```
<div class="statusbar" />
```

for a custom ios status bar.
Of a side note you may also need the meta view port tag properly added in the head as well. E.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

This tag is not needed for the status bar, but for using a splash or loading screen. A user on [medium](https://medium.com/@applification/progressive-web-app-splash-screens-80340b45d210) did an article for setting up the splash screen.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Also, as apple has limited support for the manifest file & has changed their pwa support in the past, these tags may eventually become deprecated and they may end up using the manifest.json file properly.